# HP ProBook 450 G2 has slow wireless connection

Tags: wireless-networking, bluetooth

Ever since I bought my HP ProBook 450 G2 a few months ago I have noticed that the Internet was slow.  Although I have a 18 Mbps connection, download speed tests were only showing between 5 and 6 Mbps.  Common recommendations for wireless problems are:

- Check your router
- Update your wireless drivers
- Check for any interfering devices

I ruled out the router since my old laptop was getting 18Mbps wireless download speed while it was sitting right next to my HP ProBook.  And that seemed to rule out interference too.  I also updated the wireless adapter drivers to the latest versions, but that didn't help either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a whole lot of Internet searching, I finally found the solution in a [post where someone stated that it worked fine in safe mode](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-networking/slow-wireless-internet-works-fine-in-safe-mode/081f777c-b004-4e44-8a3b-a1d5d5cfddee?rtAction=1452189494703).  In that post, Rick (TurskRO) says "The HP Probook 450 G2 has a problem with the WiFi and Bluetooth combo card. If you turn the bluetooth off via their utility then the wireless will become full speed. Turn bluetooth back on and the speed is a crawl. I have talked with HP about this and they say their is no fix."

Turning off Bluetooth using the HP Connection Manager did solve the problem for me and allowed full speed downloads.  I had tried turning off the Bluetooth via Services in Control Panel, and I tried turning it off in the system tray, but neither of those methods worked.  To turn off with the HP Connection Manager:

1. Open HP Connection Manager from the "Productivity and Tools" folder in the Start menu
2. Click the blue Power icon in the Bluetooth row to turn it off

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Do you know if there is any way to switch Bluetooth off on Windows 10?